# HTML <video> tag is not working on perl

Tags: html, perl, video, cgi

I am trying to play the video from the `<video>` tag with the cgi script.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header(
        -type=> "text/html" );

print <<EOF;
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="/home/ubuntu_Workspace/c/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video> 
EOF
```

When i keep the file in the server i can play it.But if i keep the video file in some other directory it wont play the video instead it will give the error.

After doing some research i came to know that it should be in the path where server can access that directory.So the most cases it would be `/var/www/` path.But what should i do when the video files are in the different 
paths.I mean it could be able to play the file whichever path it may be.

please suggest me on this where i am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it must be inside the webserver's root directory. That's because it's not you *as the CGI program* playing the video, but it's *you as the user of the website* playing it.

The user's browser needs to download the video while playing it. That's called streaming. In order to download it, it needs to be accessible.

Where your webserver's directory for websites is depends on your web server, your operating system and your configuration. Since you seem to be able to run the Perl script, just put the video next to that script file.

Comment: But as per my requirement the video file may be anywhere in the system i could be able to play it...how can i do it??

Comment: Open the file with another program and stream it from that program instead of pointing to the file directly.

Comment: can you give me a simple example